# The custom iCheck design of the radio button prevents the output of Total price when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I was trying to understand why is it that when I click my radio button, I do not see the output of the total price, but when I ran my code in jsfiddle or in a seperate test.php page where I did not refer the script for the iCheck, the total price output was showing. How does the design of the iCheck interfere? And how can I fix this issue?

icheck.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').iCheck({
   checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
   radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
  increaseArea: '20%' // optional
 });
});
```

price.js //outputs the Total price when the radio button is clicked

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  //alert();
     $(document).on("click", ".btn-checkbox-plan", function(e){
       if($(".btn-checkbox-plan").is(':checked')){

        $("#output").html($(this).val());
       }

     });  

    });
```

Code:

```
<div class="checkout">
                    <span id="checkout-title">Checkout</span>
                    <div class="plan-wrapper">
                        <input class="btn-checkbox-plan" type="radio" name="groupnine" value="$699" /> <label id="silver-plan">Silver Plan</label>
                        <label id="silver-plan-price">$699</label>
                        <input class="btn-checkbox-plan" type="radio" name="groupnine" value="$999" /> <label id="gold-plan"> Gold Plan</label>
                        <label id="gold-plan-price">$999</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="logo-wrapper">
                        <span id="personalized-logo">Personalized Logo</span>
                        <span id="logo-price">$49.99</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tax-wrapper">
                        <div class="wrapper-a">
                            <span id="tax">Tax + Processing</span>
                            <span id="tax-price">$0.00</span>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="total-wrapper">
                        <div class="wrapper-b">
                            <span id="total">Total</span>
                            <output type="number" name="price" id="output"></output>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls submit-btn">
                        <input  type="submit" value="Checkout" />
                        <input  type="reset" value="Clear" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls back-btn">
                        <input  class="back-button" type="button" value="Back" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the callbacks http://fronteed.com/iCheck/

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
  alert(event.type + ' callback');
});
```